# What do I need to point my makefile at to make it build a kernel driver properly?

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, debian, linux-device-driver

I am working on a simple driver for a class. I am using this makefile:

```
obj-m := mysourcefile.o

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel

all default: modules
install: modules_install

modules modules_install help clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(pwd) $@
```

When I run this using the line:

```
make
```

I get the error:

```
no rule to make target 'modules'. Stop.
```

I do want to note, my textbook suggests this line:

```
KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
```

However, I have no "build" directory in my version of Debian (10.6.0-3) (Kernel v. 4.19.0-10-amd64), so I changed the file to point to kernel, since I believe the makefile is supposed to point to the kernel. I don't know if this was the correct choice or not. My active directory IS the directory which contains my source code.

I am unsure of how to proceed from this point.

Comment: "so I changed the file to point to kernel, since I believe the makefile is supposed to point to the kernel." - No, `Makefile` is contained in the **build** directory for the **kernel**. Usually. `build` subdirectory of the kernel modules points to that directory. Note, that "kernel build directory" and "my module source directory" are **different** things. "I am unsure of how to proceed from this point." - You need to find out build directory for your kernel. Debian-like distros usually provide "linux-headers" package along with the kernels provided by them.

Comment: Have you installed the `linux-headers-amd64` package? It should install `linux-headers-4.19.0-10-amd64` as a dependency if that is the latest kernel, otherwise you'll need to install it manually.

Comment: Why guess?  The instructions are in the kernel source:  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9-rc7/source/Documentation/kbuild/modules.rst